# How to edit a file which is outside my own user folder with a Chrome(ium) app?

Tags: permissions, chromium

I'm using the LXDE desktop environment (trusty 14.04), the Chromium browser and the [Text](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text/mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg?hl=en) editor app.

The problem

When I edit a file under my username (/home/henrywright) everything works fine, but when I try to edit a file stored outside my user folder (for example /var/www/html) nothing happens after I save the document.

My first thought is this could be permissions related but I'm not sure how to solve the issue. How can I save a file that I'm working on in a directory outside my own user folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just occurred to me that since you are trying to edit files in /var/www, all you need to do is add yourself to the www-data group and make some changes to director permissions

First:

```
 sudo adduser username www-data
```

Then change the directory owner and group

```
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

allow the group to write to the directory

```
 sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html
```

Now /var/www and any file or directory in it has group www-data permissions

Just log out and it again to make sure the group change takes effect

Then run from terminal

```
 groups username
```

And it will list groups you are a part of. You should see www-data. If so, go try and edit file and it will work.

Sorry this didn't occur to me first.

Edit: just to clarify, you added yourself to www-data and allowed read/write on /var/www to anyone within group www-data.

When you open chromium, it will be opened as your user, that has permissions to access the files your trying to edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the editor with sudo (or root privileges). Not sure you can do that with a Chrome app.

You may need to run chrome with sudo to get this to work.

From a terminal

```
 sudo chromium &
```

But I don't know if there are any security implications that go with this. You may want to only use the app on the browser with sudo and search Internet in another instance.

You might be better off just using a regular text editor.

Edit: Did some searching and chromium won't even run as root, unless you make some changes, so that a pretty good indication not to run as root.

Again, you may want to find a text editor you like that can be installed (not an app). The screenshot looks very similar to something that does work, but the name escapes me

Edit: As discussed it was Brackets that I was thinking of, and you like it but no arm download. I am having issues compiling on my Raspberry Pi due to PhantomJS error, but you may have better luck

Make sure you have node installed.

```
 wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.35/node-v0.10.35.tar.gz

 tar - zxvf node-v0.10.35.tar.gz
```

Once extracted cd into node directory and do the usual

```
 ./configure 
 make
 sudo make install
```

Now git brackets

```
 git clone https://github.com/adobe/brackets.git
```

Cd into Brackets directory

Run the following

```
 sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
 npm install 
 grunt
```

Then sit back and wait. Hopefully it will build for you. Like I said I'm on a Raspberry Pi, and had issues with PhantomJS, but you may not.

Comment: The problem I have with finding a text editor is, my laptop uses an ARM processor and most of the decent editors out there that are available for Linux have been complied for Intel artchitecture

Comment: The software that I was trying to think of before is called [brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets) if you want to look into it and see if seems like what you need. I won't be able to launch it to test it, but I am currently building it on my Raspberry Pi (arm chipset). So far so good, but it may take forever. Not much computing power on the pi

Comment: I love Brackets! I've been using that for the past year on my Windows PC. Problem is, it doesn't support my laptop's ARM architecture. See [here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/10298) for the issue I filed a few days ago on their GitHub support forum.

Comment: Check out my edit on answer for instructions on how to compile on your own. It may work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I seem to be having trouble compiling Brackets too. How about running Chromium apps as root (not Chromium itself, just the app)? if that's possible, would that solve my issue?

Comment: I looked into running apps with privileges and didn't find anything. Only other suggestion I can think of is install actual chrome (allow for root - Google search) and use chrome for editor and chromium as Web browser

Comment: I did try downloading Chrome but the .deb is built for Intel. I'm a noobie so am not sure how to compile binaries. Any tutorials on how to compile that you recommend I take a look at? thanks very much for your help with this by the way

Comment: See my new answer. I am 99% sure this will get the job done, and it was so simple. I was looking at it all wrong

Answer (score 0):

Linux will not allow you to change system files that you don't own unless you declare you are root. You have to make changes with sudo privileges.

Open your editor or file manager with 'sudo' at the beginning. (sudo Pcanfm or sudo leafpad)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm using the Text app which is browser based (accessed via the Chrome web app store).

Answer (score 0):

Use an editor with super user permissions:

```
$ sudo nano path-to-file
```

To own a folder, use:

```
$ sudo chown -R username:group path-to folder
```

Then you can edit without `sudo`. `group` is optional.