# How to run a Chromium app as root?

Tags: permissions, google-chrome, chromium

I need to use either the [Text](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text/mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg?hl=en) or [Caret](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret/fljalecfjciodhpcledpamjachpmelml?hl=en) editor apps to edit files in /var/www/html. My changes aren't saved (I think) because of a permissions error. I think I need to run the application as root user instead of myself (henrywright). How can I run Chromium apps as root?

Note: If possible I'd just like the app to run as root, not Chromium itself.

Comment: try sudo chromium at terminal

Comment: wouldn't that run the whole of Chromium as root?

Comment: i think yes. it may work. search whats the commands for text or caret and run them as i said that may work. i use [sublime text editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 2):

It just occurred to me that since you are trying to edit files in /var/www/html, all you need to do is add yourself to the www-data group and make some changes to director permissions

First:

```
 sudo adduser username www-data
```

Then change the directory owner and group

```
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

allow the group to write to the directory

```
 sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html
```

Now /var/www and any file or directory in it has group www-data permissions

Just log out and it again to make sure the group change takes effect

Then run from terminal

```
 groups username
```

And it will list groups you are a part of. You should see www-data. If so, go try and edit file and it will work.

Sorry this didn't occur to me first.

Edit: just to clarify, you added yourself to www-data and allowed read/write on /var/www to anyone within group www-data.

When you open chromium, it will be opened as your user, that has permissions to access the files your trying to edit

Comment: Any luck? Cause this should do it

Comment: thanks for these instructions. I followed them step by step but am still unable to save a file to the /var/www/html location. I noticed the instructions relate to /var/www. Will these changes propagate to the /html etc subfolders?

Comment: The -R was for recursive, so it should have changed html. Redo the commands but this time do /var/www/html

Comment: Actually just do sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html and it will work.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the /var/www/html, but like I said, just do the sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html and it will work. Before we only gave you read/write on /var/www and not html

Comment: Great - thank you for all your help today! I've marked [your answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/568731/how-to-edit-a-file-which-is-outside-my-own-user-folder-with-a-chromeium-app) as accepted as I'd still like to know how to run Chromium apps as root user (i.e. this question) :)

Comment: If it worked could you please mark answer as accented. I already updated it to match your /var/www/html (sorry messed up first time, I always adjust document root to be just /var/www)

Comment: Already done, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/568731/how-to-edit-a-file-which-is-outside-my-own-user-folder-with-a-chromeium-app) - thanks again!

Comment: `Step 1. Open /etc/chromium/default file with editor`
`Step 2. Replace or add this line 
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--password-store=detect --user-data-dir=/root/chrome-profile/"`
`Step 3. Save it..` you should now be able to run as root, but again, it probably not the best idea

Comment: Yeah I definitely agree it isn't the best idea to run Chromium as root. I was wondering if I could run individual Chromium apps as root, for example Text.app or Caret (or is that impossible?)

Comment: I couldn't find anything

Comment: same here! Hopefully someone will stumble upon this question having experienced the problem themselves. Now that Chrome apps are becoming popular, it must be something that has come up in the past